# 2013 Festive season bike decoration competition

Tags: discussion, contest

**The 2013 Festive Season bike decoration competition is now open**

Submit photos of any bike with or without rider, decorated as appropriate for the Festive Season, with or without accompanying text. No religious affiliation intended.

Please be aware of the need for safety.

The winner is the entry with the most votes at the start of the new year, UTC (or as near as I can make it). In the event of a tie I will make the casting vote. I will not be entering the competition.

When you vote for an entry please post a comment about what you like.

Comment: @freiheit Thanks for migrating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: tall bike christmas tree]

Sorry, best photo I could find of it.

Comment: Fantastic! Great work!

Comment: Appolgies for the late response (death in the family). I wonder if your amazing entry psyched others out, or if hard-core cyclists are boring :-) Either way, thanks for contributing, you are hereby announced as the winner!

Comment: Yeah, I dunno, it's odd. Possibly that does raise the bar as it's a tall bike (rare), decorated (moderately hard to do) *and* there's a costume (more work). Now I look at it more I notice that that was before I put the santa hat on my helmet.

Comment: Yep, it's a good job. I was expecting some tinsel, a few lights, and maybe a Santa hat or reindeer antlers.